# 3rd and 4th Edition of Royden's Real Analysis Book

Tags: reference-request, book-recommendation

Does anyone have experience with the 3rd and 4th edition of Royden's Real Analysis (from my understanding, the 4th edition is due entirely the work of a later author Fitzpatrick). From the reviews on Amazon, the 'consensus' seems to be that Fitzpatrick ruined Royden's text and that it is better to work with the third edition (indeed, one reviewer went so far as to say "Royden [is] rolling in his grave", which gave me a good chuckle)? Is this true?

The 4th edition boasts having 50% more problems over the 3rd edition. But many of these added problems are pretty trivial, or are such that the preceding text doesn't fully equip one to solve them, in a logical sense. Also, when I quickly thumbed through the third edition, I noticed that the theorems that appear in the 4th edition appear in the third edition but with less hypotheses, possibly hinting at the fact that topics in the 3rd edition are treated with slightly more generality. Perhaps I'm mistaken, though.

These are just a few things I noticed. I'm hoping that someone with more experience with these two editions could weigh in on this matter.

Comment: What specific question are you hoping to get answered?

Comment: When I took my first semester of graduate analysis, my professor recommended specifically the third edition of Royden. I haven't used the fourth, though.

Comment: @AirConditioner Hmm...I guess I wasn't terribly clear about that. I apologize. My question is, should I stop using the fourth edition and move to the third edition.